Need the right flag, im not sure what it is
I'm a begginer in modding, specifically modding for The Binding of Isaac Repentance so Lua is new to me. The mod is supposed to upgrade your damage and size and lower your speed. Right now the dmg and speed modifications work pretty well but the size up doesn't seem to work.
This is my code, feel free to read it and torn it apart if you need it.
Also, all credits go to catinsurance on yt whose tutorial did this.
local mod = RegisterMod("More food!", 1)
    local clownBurger = Isaac.GetItemIdByName("Clown's Burger!")
    local clownBurgerDamage = 3
    local clownBurgerSpeed = 0.5
    local clownBurgerSize = 100 --tried with 2 at first but nothing really changed
    function mod:EvaluateCacheDmg(player, cacheFlags)
        if cacheFlags & CacheFlag.CACHE_DAMAGE == CacheFlag.CACHE_DAMAGE then 
            local itemCount = player:GetCollectibleNum(clownBurger)
            local damageToAdd = clownBurgerDamage * itemCount
            player.Damage = player.Damage + damageToAdd
            end
        end
    mod:AddCallback(ModCallbacks.MC_EVALUATE_CACHE, mod.EvaluateCacheDmg)
    function mod:EvaluateCacheSpd(player, cacheFlags)
        if cacheFlags & CacheFlag.CACHE_SPEED == CacheFlag.CACHE_SPEED then
            local itemCount = player:GetCollectibleNum(clownBurger)
            local speedToDecrease = clownBurgerSpeed * itemCount
            player.MoveSpeed = player.MoveSpeed - speedToDecrease
            end
        end
    mod:AddCallback(ModCallbacks.MC_EVALUATE_CACHE, mod.EvaluateCacheSpd)
    function mod:EvaluateCacheSize(player, cacheFlags)
        if cacheFlags & CacheFlag.CACHE_SIZE == CacheFlag.CACHE_SIZE then
            local itemCount = player:GetCollectibleNum(clownBurger)
            local sizeToAdd = clownBurgerSize * itemCount
            player.Size = player.Size + sizeToAdd
            end
        end
    mod:AddCallback(ModCallbacks.MC_EVALUATE_CACHE, mod.EvaluateCacheSize)

